# Editing datetime in csv to adjust time zone

Tags: bash, csv, datetime, awk

We routinely get csv files containing datetime values in certain columns that are always GMT.
We are looking for a way to change the datetime values from GMT to a time zone of our choice - the desired target time zone may differ from one csv to the next.  The adjustment would need to account for DST also.

Datetime Format from csv:

```
YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS
```

Sample data:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
aaa,bbb,2016/01/15 22:01:16,ccc
ddd,eee,,fff
hhh,iii,2014/09/19 00:53:37,jjj
kkk,lll,2015/11/15 22:01:16,mmm
nnn,ooo,2015/10/12 19:54:59,ppp
```

For example, if we want to adjust the sample data above from GMT to Pacific time (GMT -8 standard), our desired result would be a csv with values as follows:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
aaa,bbb,2016/01/15 14:01:16,ccc
ddd,eee,,fff
hhh,iii,2014/09/18 17:53:37,jjj
kkk,lll,2015/11/15 14:01:16,mmm
nnn,ooo,2015/10/12 12:54:59,ppp
```

Note re DST:  for the 5 lines of sample data above, DST was active for dates on lines 3 and 5 only.  The adjustment may be different from line to line, but is consistent in terms of the target time zone equivalent (Pacific).

The datetime format itself can stay as is - we need only to adjust the datetime value for time zone and ultimately store the equivalent datetime in Eastern, Pacific, (or any other time zone) instead of GMT.

If possible we would like to leverage editing tools available natively in Ubuntu like awk as we already have cleanup routines that utilize it.  Will consider other solutions if an awk or similar solution isn't possible.

Other notes:

- Some csv's have datetimes in multiple columns where only ***some*** of the columns require adjustment from GMT to another timezone.  Ideal solution would adjust datetimes in one or more columns that we designate but skip columns that do not need adjustment.
- The csv columns having datetimes may also include blank values on some lines.
- On a per csv basis, we would want to change datetimes from GMT to a single target time zone, the same tz adjustment would be done for all rows.

Any insight is appreciated - thanks!

EDIT:

In researching this, I've found that a statement like this:

```
echo "1/15/2016  10:01:16 GMT" | awk -v q='"' '{cmd="TZ=America/Los_Angeles date -d"q$0 q" +"q"%F %H:%M:%S %Z"q; cmd|getline x; close(cmd);print x}'
```

...is somewhat a proof of concept, but 1) I had to add "GMT" to the string myself, and 2) the output date format is slightly different.
I'm hoping to find a solution I can apply to csv's that may have thousands of rows.

Comment: first of all: where do i send the invoice?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please show your coding efforts.

Comment: Edited post to add a sample awk statement / concept showing a single value tz conversion.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU awk for time functions:

```
$ cat tst.awk
function dt2utcSecs(dateTime,   cmd,line,ret) {
    cmd = "TZ=UTC gawk -v dt='" dateTime "' 'BEGIN{print mktime(dt)}'"
    ret = ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ? line : -1 )
    close(cmd)
    return ret
}
BEGIN{
    FS=OFS=","
    split(cols,f)
}
{
    for (i in f) {
        dateTime = gensub(/[\/:]/," ","g",$(f[i]))
        utcSecs = dt2utcSecs(dateTime)
        if (utcSecs >= 0) {
            $(f[i]) = strftime("%Y/%m/%d %T",utcSecs)
        }
    }
    print
}

$ TZ='US/Pacific' gawk -v cols=3 -f tst.awk file
col1,col2,col3,col4
aaa,bbb,2016/01/15 14:01:16,ccc
ddd,eee,,fff
hhh,iii,2014/09/18 17:53:37,jjj
kkk,lll,2015/11/15 14:01:16,mmm
nnn,ooo,2015/10/12 12:54:59,ppp
```

Just set `cols=3,5,9` to do the conversion on those fields. See /usr/share/zoneinfo for a list of valid time zones.

Note that [@webb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39502756/1745001) should be more efficient than the above since the above calls shell to call gawk once per input dateTime field while @webbs just calls gawk twice.

Comment: Thank you @ed-morton!  I think this is working on my end - just running some more tests - will keep you posted.

Answer (score 1):

here's an amusing way:

first, convert date strings to numeric, utc timestamps, then, convert the numeric timestamps to local date strings:

```
TZ=UTC awk -F, '
  BEGIN{OFS=","}
  { if(NR>1&&$3){
      gsub("[/:]"," ",$3);
      $3=mktime($3" GMT")};
    print $0
  }' infile.csv | awk  -F, '
  BEGIN{OFS=","}
  { if(NR>1&&$3){
      $3=strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S %Z", $3, 0)};
    print $0
  }' > outfile.csv
```

output:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
aaa,bbb,2016/01/15 14:01:16 PST,ccc
ddd,eee,,fff
hhh,iii,2014/09/18 17:53:37 PDT,jjj
kkk,lll,2015/11/15 14:01:16 PST,mmm
nnn,ooo,2015/10/12 12:54:59 PDT,ppp
```

note 1: you can remove the timezone from the output by removing the `%Z` in the second `awk`, but if you do that, you're only hurting your future self.

note 2: this may or may not work depending on your version of `awk`. if your system has `gawk`, try that in place of `awk`. if not, it should be easy to install `gawk`.

Comment: You can run `TZ=UTC0 gawk '…' | TZ=US/Pacific gawk '…'` setting the time zone explicitly for each.  Or, if you want just current local time for the second, use `TZ=UTC0 gawk '…' | gawk '…'`.  The notation sets the environment variable for the command (not pipeline) that follows.

Comment: thanks, jonathan. i tried what i thought was the second option and it didn't work, but i must have tried something different, because it does work now. btw, what would `TZ=UTC` vs `TZ=UTC0` do?

Comment: Succinctly, `TZ=UTC0` is a POSIX-compliant time zone variable setting where the zone abbreviation is UTC, the offset from UTC is 0, and there is no rule for 'summer time'. Using `TZ=UTC` is using a non-standard form (as is `US/Pacific`) which might, or might not, translate to the same thing as `TZ=UTC0`. The chances are good that `TZ=UTC` does have the same effect as `TZ=UTC0`, but it isn't guaranteed, and there are a number of different ways in which the system could arrive at the conclusion about which time zone offset to use (some of the details of which depend on the system in use!).

Comment: Nice approach, just a few comments: 1) test for `$3!=""` instead of just `$3` in the 2nd script at least or it'll fail for `1970/1/1 00:00:00` since that's 0 secs. 2) gsub()s first arg is a regexp, not a string so use regexp `/.../`, not string `"..."` delimiters.  3) Addiing `" GMT"` to the mktime() timestamp will do nothing. 4) Don't set FS and OFS separately to the same value, set them together `BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}`. 5) The 3rd arg to strftime() is only needed when it's `1`. 6) The trailing semicolons aren't doing anything. 7) The `$0` in `print $0` does nothing. 8) Use `cond { act }` syntax.

Comment: Thanks @webb - when i try it i get:  awk: cmd. line:4: (FILENAME=- FNR=2) fatal: strftime: second argument less than 0 or too big for time_t
I'll keep poking around.  Tried gawk also and got same error.